# Не считывается символ + из файла php.

Tags: php

есть задача. Исходные два числа хранятся в текстовом файле в произвольной последовательности. По нажатию кнопки Вычислить результат выводится в форму. Проблема в том, что из файла получается считать только числа, но сложить их нельзя. Пыталась считать файлы посимвольно и если один из элементов равен плюсу, то остальные числа сложить, но ничего не получилось. Прошу помощи, т.к. в php еще новичок.

[image: Данные в файле[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMtmf.jpg)

```
 <?php
function getPlus($a, $b){
    return $a+$b;
}
function getMinus($a, $b){
    return $a-$b;
}
function plus(){
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("don't connect with mysql");
     mysql_select_db("exam",$db) or die ("don't connect with db");
     $file = 'data.txt';
     $f = fopen($file,"r") or "don't open file";
     $a = Array();
     while (($data = fgets($f))!=false){
         $a0 = explode(" ",$data);
         foreach ($a0 as $item)
            if (is_numeric(trim($item)))
                $a[] = $item;
     }
     fclose($f);
foreach($a as $item) echo $item;
$char = '+';
     // $res = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    if ()
    {$res = $a[1]+$a[2];}
}
echo $res;
}

if (isset($_GET['button'])){
    plus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

есть много вариантов

```
<?php
 $file = file('file.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); // читаем фаил в массив
 $file = array_map('trim', $file); // тримим
 $plus = array_search('+', $file); // ищем плюс
 $result = 0;

 if($plus !== false) { // если нашли
     unset($file[$plus]); //убираем его с массива 
     $result = array_sum($file); // суммируем массив
     echo $result . ' ok';
 } else {
     echo 'error';
 }
```

Comment: На самом деле это не сильно "короче" ибо по операциям и по памяти выходит одно и тоже, тем более я изначально писал под несколько знаков (ибо в вопросе там какие-то функции с плюсом и минус непонятные). Так что минус. Ах да: `array_summ`=>`array_sum`

Comment: @Manitikyl причем тут короче или длинее или короче? У твоего кода сложность алгоритма о в степени н, моего о умноженное на н. И нормы оформления нарушены

Comment: @Nuamov стандарты оформления - я выберу пожалуй для себя сам. Сложность алгоритма? для массива из 3ех элементов? я вас умоляю....

Comment: элегантное решение, легко читаемо, без циклов. Плюсую

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$trimmed = file('sum_nums.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$stack = [];
$op = '';
// Expression that can be calculated
$expr = ['+', '-', '/', '*'];
foreach($trimmed as $line_num => $line){
    // 
    if(in_array($line, $expr)){
        $op = $line;
    }else{// Numbers
        $stack[] = (int)$line;
    }
    // Calculate 
    if(count($stack) == 2 && !empty($op)){
       echo sprintf("%d %s %d = %d", $stack[0] , $op , $stack[1] ,eval('return ' .$stack[0] .$op. $stack[1] . ';')) . "\n";
        // Empty array and operation
        $stack = [];
        $op = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Ну как вариант :<

```
$FILE = 'data.txt';
$ARRAY = array_filter(file($FILE), function($value) {
    return !empty(trim($value));
});
$RESPONSE = NULL;
foreach ($ARRAY as $key => $value) {
    if (($value == '+') OR ($value == '-')) {
        unset($ARRAY[$key]);
        foreach ($ARRAY as $value2) {
            if (is_numeric($value2)) {
                switch ($value) {
                    case '+':
                        if (is_null($RESPONSE)) {
                            $RESPONSE = 0;
                        }
                        $RESPONSE += $value2;
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        if (is_null($RESPONSE)) {
                            $RESPONSE = $value2;
                        }
                        $RESPONSE -= $value2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($RESPONSE);
```

А если просто сложить, то так:

```
$FILE = 'data.txt';
$ARRAY = array_filter(file($FILE), function($value) {
    return !empty(trim($value));
});
$RESPONSE = 0;
foreach ($ARRAY as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == '+') {
        unset($ARRAY[$key]);
        foreach ($ARRAY as $value2) {
            if (is_numeric($value2)) {
                $RESPONSE += $value2;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($RESPONSE);
```

Comment: с точки зрения кода и оформления очень плохие варианты

Comment: @Naumov с адекватной точки зрения, предложите лучше. Если нет, то не надо меня учить. Договорились?

Comment: Я на личности не переходил а вот с точки зрения кода:
1. Есть array_filter вместо array_diff 
2. Переменные большими буквами (константы с большой буквы пишут)
3. NULL и OR вообще молчу ты хоть знаешь чем OR от || отличается?
4. foreach array_search заменяет
5. key. в foreache можно не использовать передав value по ссылке в версии 7 и так по умолчанию

Comment: @Naumov Где и кто перешел на личности? 1) Код не притендует на оптимальность - это вполне логично, как и ваш.. 2) Я могу использовать любой пул функций для достижения результата. 3) Переменные я буду называть как мне угодно, и как я привык, а не как Вам надо. (Константы пишут без $ спереди - иронию думаю поняли). 4) разный приоритет, и в чем проблема, видимо вы не знаете чем отличаются? 5) NULL - тоже вполне логично, тут все норм. 5) еще раз, я писал под нескольких знаков и второй вариант краткая версия первого.

Comment: facepalm когда пишешь для себя хоть $t и $b называй. А когда выставляешь свой код на публики, будь мужчиной и выслушай критику людей которые работают в команде уже не первый год

Comment: @Naumov давай пипками померимся? Я думаю ты проиграешь. Так что не надо тут. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Я тебе умоляю что тут мериться, по коду видно что обычный жун фулстек битриксойд

Comment: Так и быть черт с этим баном на стек, сможешь оптимально проверить регуляркой что число 1022 находится между 1000 и 1050?

Comment: xD Okay. Сеньиор, по коду я тоже могу кучу всего сказать: сделать для нескольких знаков будет приблизительно такой-же вариант это раз, во вторых входные данные ВСЕГДА должны фильртоваться, а вы складываете не понятно что, третье - у меня нет мотивации сидеть и давать грамотные ответы, я что написал, то и будет, экономя свое время, а ты уже был смотивирован, и если это твой "примерный" код, то мне тебя жаль, я тогда скажу что ты от джуна не дальше меня ушел это точно))

Comment: @Naumov Очень разумно сравнивать числа регулярками, я думаю вам на ноде надо кодить. Думаю там ваша стихия.

Comment: согласен с Naumov, код далек от совершенства. Вам нужно просветиться о таких функциях PHP как array_sum (вместо цикла), почитать про приведение типов - в частности проверка на empty() - избыточна. В любом случае спасибо за труды, думаю кому-то и такой вариант будет полезен

Comment: @PHPLego `array_sum()` можно юзать при условии если вы на 100% уверены что там цифры. У меня-же не просто цикл, а с проверкой на условие. Если вы не проверяете входные данные, то ваш код далек от совершенства... Не надо меня учить функциям и тем более как кодить я все и без прекрасно знаю.

Comment: @PHPLego проверка на `empty` избыточна? Если вы не разбираетесь, зачем постить свое мнение? Вот она уж точно не избыточно, ибо в файле могут быть отступы (например в конце файла), может быть строка но не пустая (например с пробелом). В следующий раз воздержитесь от комментариев в мой адрес. Сразу скажу, что `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` - не спасает от строк с пробелом :<